# What is the concept in jenkins act as bamboo test streams

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

In my project I have more than 20 test cases. I previously used the bamboo test streams to run this test cases parallel. When moving to the jenkins, how can I divide these test cases to several streams in order to minimize the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) and [Build Flow Test Aggregator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Test+Aggregator+Plugin) can do what you want.

- The Build Flow plugin supports running jobs in parallel. It could schedule your "child" job to run in parallel with different parameters.
- The Build Flow Test Aggregator grabs test results from the scheduled builds of a Build Flow job, so your "child" job will need to publish its own test results.
- You will need to configure your "child" job so that it can run in parallel by checking the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" in the job configuration.
- Whatever set of slaves provide the connection to the embedded devices will need enough executors to run your jobs in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and I'll try out this way.